# Morris Line Chart: get point value when clicked

Tags: javascript, morris.js

Unfortunately after going through a day looking for an answer on this issue, I'm not able to find it anywhere.  Would appreciate if someone could help me out here:

I would like to obtain the point value of what the user clicks.  So, for example in the attached image, when the user click as shown, I want to get the value being 'ra_user3'.  I'm currently getting ra_user1 which is not correct.  I'm getting the correct clickedDate though.

[image]

My JS code:

```js
// LINE QaqcRA_CHART qaqc
var QaqcRA_user_color = <?php echo json_encode($QaqcRA_user_color); ?>;
var QaqcRA_user_label = <?php echo json_encode($QaqcRA_user_label); ?>;
var QaqcRA_users = <?php echo json_encode($QaqcRA_users); ?>;

var line = new Morris.Line({
  element: 'QaqcRA_charts',
  resize: true,
  data: <?php echo json_encode($QaqcRA_charts); ?>,
  parseTime: false,
  xkey: 'ra_updated_on',
  xLabels: 'Inspection Date',
  xLabelAngle: 45,
  hideHover: 'false',
  ykeys: QaqcRA_user_label,
  labels: QaqcRA_user_label,
  lineColors: QaqcRA_user_color,
  hoverCallback: function(index, options, content, row) {

    var finalContent = content;

    return finalContent;
  }
});

$("#QaqcRA_charts svg").on('click', function(evt) {

  var a = evt.target;
  var target_result = JSON.stringify(a);
  console.log("target_result: " + target_result); // target_result: {"raphael":true,"raphaelid":139}

  var clickedDate = $(".morris-hover-row-label").html().trim();
  var clickedPoint = $(".morris-hover-point").html().trim();
  var comp = clickedPoint.split(":");
  var clickedUser = comp[0];

  console.log("clickedDate: " + clickedDate); // clickedDate: 20 May 2020
  console.log("clickedUser: " + clickedUser); // clickedUser: ra_user1

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you use to intercept the click event is not good. You should write something like:

```js
    var line = new Morris.Line({
      element: 'QaqcRA_charts',
      resize: true,
      data: <?php echo json_encode($QaqcRA_charts); ?>,
      parseTime: false,
      xkey: 'ra_updated_on',
      xLabels: 'Inspection Date',
      xLabelAngle: 45,
      hideHover: 'false',
      ykeys: QaqcRA_user_label,
      labels: QaqcRA_user_label,
      lineColors: QaqcRA_user_color,
      hoverCallback: function(index, options, content, row) {

        var finalContent = content;

        return finalContent;
      }
    }).on('click', function(a, row) {
      // here you should be able to handle the click event
      console.log(a,row);
    });
```

Then you would have access to the series of data for the xkey you clicked;

Comment: as per your suggestion. i'm getting a=2 and row={"ra_updated_on":"20 May 2020","ra_user1":"0","ra_user2":"15","ra_user3":"9"}.  It's not giving me the exact 'ra_user3' that was clicked.  a here is referring to the second element of X-axis.  i'm still missing the Y-axis.  would appreciate if you could help further.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you cannot get the exact point you clicked in the series, that is not available in MorrisJS so far. The only way would be to add a click event on the circle, but that is a kind of big job.